# Creating a new Blog with Octopress

Tags: octopress

I am reading this tutorial to create a new blog using the octopress

http://octopress.org/docs/setup/

I have successfully installed all the reuqired software and also created a heroku account.

I have also completed this step of configuring octopress with heroku

http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/heroku/

Now I am at the step where I have to configure the _config.yml file.

http://octopress.org/docs/configuring/

I am a little confused here as to what should I really put in this file.

Can anyone share a sample or some guidance on how can I complete this step and go about my first post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have it for an Octopress in Heroku:

In the config.yml fill in your url, title, subtitle, author, description

The rest of the defaults should work.

If you have a custom domain you have to add a CNAMe file.

To create a new post you use rake as in `rake new_post['Name of awesome post']`

Then open that post. It is under the folder `source/_posts`

Add contents after the yml header

Save file.

Then follow the steps of deployment.

I documented an octopress to heroku deployment on my blog here:

http://www.tomordonez.com/blog/2012/07/22/set-up-a-blog-with-an-html5-template-in-octopress-and-heroku-cloud-service/

There is no mystery to it. If you have more questions tweet me @tomordonez or reply back with your results